# Why getValue() function calls so many times in product list page Magento 2

Tags: magento2

in my di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice" type="vendor\module\TestPricing\Price\FinalPrice" />
```

why getValue() function calls so many time? and where from call is coming?

```
namespace vendor\module\TestPricing\Price;


class FinalPrice extends  \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice
{
    public $_objectManager, $_global_helper;

    public function getValue()
    {
        $logger = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class);
        $logger->info($this->product['sku']);
        return 4;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On Category List Page, there are many products list from the same category.

Each product have it's own price.
That price is display in the category list page.

So it call for each product on category list page.

Comment: ok thanks for answer, but for each product logger work 8 times, what is making calls for my functtion?

Comment: Yes, if you have diffrent things like special price, product options etc then it will call.